# Cannot start web console of ActiveMQ Artemis embedded within JBoss EAP 7.2

Tags: activemq-artemis, jboss-eap-7

I am new to messaging using ActiveMQ Artemis that is embedded within JBoss EAP 7.2. I have started JBoss EAP in full mode when the Active MQ Artemis broker is also started. but when I open http://localhost:8161, the web console of MQ is not starting up. Can you please guide me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web console which runs on port 8161 by default is not included with JBoss EAP. That specific console run with ActiveMQ Artemis standalone. JBoss EAP has its own web console which runs on port 9990 by default. JBoss EAP also has its own management API, XML configuration, etc. for the embedded ActiveMQ Artemis instance.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to access the management API of ActiveMQ Artemis embedded in JBoss EAP?

Comment: @Anirban can we really access the AMQ management console in JBoss? I know its you old query, but what was the outcome.. you were able to access or not possible?

Comment: @sakura yes it is accessible from JBoss EAP console -> Runtime -> Logging -> Default and there you can see the list of queues, queue depth etc.

Comment: @Anirban, that's the JBoss EAP web console, not the AMQ web console. The two consoles are quite different from one another.

Comment: @sakura, to my knowledge you can't access the AMQ web console from EAP (as stated in my answer). Furthermore, you wouldn't really want to because EAP has its own management API, XML configuration, etc. If it were actually possible to use the AMQ web console you'd bypass the EAP management layer which means changes you made would not be reflected in the XML, etc.

Comment: Yes @JustinBertram, here ActiveMQ Artemis is managed by JBoss EAP and there is no separate broker of ActiveMQ Artemis. So we will have to access the queues only through JBoss EAP web console

Comment: @sakura sorry for a typo above, we can see the queues under Messaging and not Logging